# Error:Integer value required in Opencv Python SVM

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I wrote a code for training a particular data set using SVM using Opencv in Python(this is only part of the total code).

```
svm_params = dict( kernel_type = cv2.ml.SVM_LINEAR ,svm_type = cv2.ml.SVM_C_SVC,C=2.67, gamma=3 )
svm = cv2.ml.SVM_create()
trainingData,labels = getTrainingData()
svm.train(trainingData, labels, params=svm_params)
svm.save('svm_data.dat')
```

trainingData and labels are lists of features and responses respectively.
When I tried to run the code, I got an error which says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Python\fc.py", line 156, in <module>
    svm.train(trainingData, labels, params=svm_params)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Then I tried to convert lists of trainingData, Labels into numpy arrays.

This is the code when I converted them to numpy arrays:

```
svm_params = dict( kernel_type = cv2.ml.SVM_LINEAR ,svm_type = cv2.ml.SVM_C_SVC,C=2.67, gamma=3 )
svm = cv2.ml.SVM_create()
trainingData,labels = getTrainingData()
trainData = np.asarray(trainingData)
responses = np.asarray(labels)
svm.train(trainData, responses, params=svm_params)
svm.save('svm_data.dat')
```

Then it gave some other error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Python\fc.py", line 155, in <module>
    svm.train(trainData, responses, params=svm_params)
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

trainingData and labels are features and their corresponding responses. I tried to print trainingData and labels: First few rows of trainingData are:

```
 [0, 300, 866, 214, 120, 38] [[0, 140, 1620, 276, 162, 18], [0, 111, 1085, 207, 132, 12], [0, 102, 570, 174, 102, 10],..
```

Labels:

```
 [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1],...
```

What changes should I make for my code to successfully train the data?

Comment: Show how you tried to convert `trainingData` and `labels` into numpy arrays please. Can you also show a couple of rows of `trainingData` and `labels`? The first error is happening because it wants something to be integer and I wonder if your `labels` are the problem.

Comment: Can you explain what `trainingData` and `labels` are? I.e., what types, what sizes, etc.

Comment: (1) Put that in the question. (2) Change to `responses = np.array(labels).flatten()` to change `labels` from being a list of lists to just being an array of ints.

Comment: I tried as you said. But Iam still getting the same error.